# WebScraping using python

Tags: python

I'm **scraping** all the comments from https://www.consumeraffairs.com/privacy/transunion.html website

```
    page_list = []
    def pagination(soup):
        for i in range(0,32):
            domain = "https://www.consumeraffairs.com/privacy/transunion.html?page="+str(i)                        
            page_list.append(domain)
        return page_list
    pages = pagination(soup)

    print(pages)
```

how to capture the comments under these pages as it shows

```
    import time
    comment_list = []
    def get_comments(urls):
        for url in urls:
            try:
                print(url)
                #comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'rvw-bd'})
                comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'rvw-bd'})             
                print(len(comment))
                for x in range(len(comment)):
                    comment_list.append(comment[x].p.text.strip())            
            except:
                continue
                time.sleep(30)
        return comment_list
    comments = get_comments(pages)
```

I used this code but it scraps only first 10 in first page. how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track changing the "page=" value in the url, but from the code you posted, it doesn't seem like you changed the soup object to represent the content of each new page. I rewrote some of your code to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

page_list = []
for i in range(0,32):
    domain = "https://www.consumeraffairs.com/privacy/transunion.html?page="+str(i)                        
    page_list.append(domain)

comment_list = []
for page in page_list:
    try:
        content = requests.get(page).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        #comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'rvw-bd'})

        comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'rvw-bd'})             
        print(len(comment))

        for x in range(len(comment)):
            comment_list.append(comment[x].p.text.strip())            
    except:
        continue
        time.sleep(30)

print(comment_list)
print(len(comment_list))
```

Let me know if this does/doesn't help!